# Open Emulator inside of Android Studio as a tab on the side

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

Is there anyway to get the emulator working INSIDE of Android Studio?
I already checked "Launch in a tool window" and restarted Android Studio multiple times, I still can't get the result I want.
Any Trick?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45145168/can-i-run-the-android-emulator-within-or-on-top-of-the-android-studio-window

Comment: Yes. It still doesn't work...

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you g et an error?

Comment: No, the emulator just keeps launching in a seperate window and as I showed in the screenshot, I still don't see the emulator option under view -> Tool windows

Comment: Is the option under  `File > Settings > Tools > Emulator` then try  `select Launch in a tool window and click OK`

Comment: I already did as I showed in the second screenshot. I didn't help either (after restarting both PC and Android Studio)

Comment: I dont know the answer sorry. Maybe ask help from android studio customer service (If that exists?) And else, do you really need to open the emulator inside android studio?

Comment: Yes, because every time I click outside the emulator it minimizes and I have to click on it again to get it back to the forground. It kinda bothers when you have a small monitor and you have half of Android studio empty so a perfect space for the emulator that you can't use. Thanks for answering though! I will ask the Android Studio guys

Comment: No problem! Maybe size your android studio so that you have desktop space.